# How to Sort and Limit WordPress Post Links Displayed Using ACF Views Plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, sorting

I'm working on a WordPress site where I use the ACF to ACF Views plugins. This is a website where I'll publish original and translated novels. The chapters and novels are custom post types. The homepage is a query loop of the novels and each novel has its own custom fields like schedule and status. I also want to have a list of the 3 latest published chapters.

I'm using ACF Views shortcode to display the chapters that are in a bidirectional relationship with their respective novels.

Can someone help me craft a JS code to only have the links to the latest 3 posts and have them in a descended order by time?

I'm using ACF Views simple so I can't modify the Twig template code.

```html
<div class="{{ _view.classes }}acf-view acf-view--id--{{ _view.id }} acf-view--object-id--{{ _view.object_id }}">

    {% if novel_chapter_relationship.value %}

        <div class="acf-view__novel-chapter_relationship acf-view__row">

            <div class="acf-view__novel-chapter_relationship-field acf-view__field">

                {% for post_item in novel_chapter_relationship.value %}

                    <a target="{{ post_item.target }}" class="acf-view__novel-chapter_relationship-link acf-view__link" href="{{ post_item.value }}">

                        {{ post_item.linkLabel|default(post_item.title) }}

                    </a>

                {% endfor %}

            </div>

        </div>

    {% endif %}

</div>
```

I tried using JavaScript to sort and limit the posts, but it's not working as expected. I would appreciate any guidance on how to achieve this.